# Is the inverse function of an algebraic function algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, functions

Let $f$ be a real-valued function on some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$. We say that it is *algebraic* if there exists a polynomial $P \in \mathbb{R}[x,y]$ such that $P(x,f(x))=0$ identically on the domain of $f$.

Let us assume that $f$ admits an inverse: there is a function $g$ on some open subset of $\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(g(y)) = y$ and $g(f(x))=x$ whenever these equations make sense.

Is $g$ also an algebraic function?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.
Let $$Q(x,y)=P(y,x).$$
Then, writing $y=g(x)$,  $$Q(x,g(x))=P(g(x),x)=P(y,f (y))=0.$$